# Can not send XML string of a file to a get rest service

Tags: xml, rest

Hello I have developed a rest service in Meteor for receiving the content of a xml file. I have the following problem: when sending the xml ,for example

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

I only receive the first character '<'
I have not found any solution. Any idea why this happens?
Regards
Gorka

Comment: We're going to need a lot more information to be able to provide an answer. It's recommended to submit a small, complete program that reproduces the problem you're asking about. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Ok , I have just solved my answer. It is a problem with xml UTF-8 enconding. Sorry for the undefined question